# Array in a RPC/Literal wsdl

Tags: web-services, soap

I was wondering if anyone had an example of what an array would look like in a RPC/literal wsdl?  I have a rpc encoded WSDL that I am attempting to convert to rpc/literal and the sticking point are the arrays.

How would you convert

to an equivalent rpc/literal type (assuming you created an AttributeArray type)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have just little experience with SOAP. But maybe this [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996466.aspx) has just what you need. Look for the section "Describing RPC/literal messages". There is an WSDL example containing an array of customers.